# Use crontab to execute php file

Tags: bash, scripts, apache2, php, cron

I try to put this in crontab :

```
50 19 * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/phpscript.php
```

this PHP script works well with `php /var/www/html/phpscript.php`... 
I already follow many tutorials on the web, but nothing worked for me.
My crontab works because before this ligne, I have : `40 14,19,20,01 * * * /root/scripts/backup_bdd.sh` which works well.

Does someone have a solution ?
Thank you !

Comment: Look at your /var/log/syslog for the time that the cron job is supposed to run.

Comment: I only have one result concerning my PHP script  (certainly during my tests), but I don't understand well your question, I can only see the moment when CRON was running scripts

Comment: If there was no error output that needed to be mailed to you, then the script ran successfully as far as cron could tell. Your question does not specify what leads to you believe that something is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. What leads me to belive that the scripts isn't executed is that the script use a REST API, and running I PHP, the script modify informations in the REST back office. My last error was `Feb 11 19:02:45 localhost systemd-resolved[2141121]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.` returned by `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of burying important information in comments. The purpose of comments is for us to help you improve your question until it is answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run through `cron`, `crontab`, aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.

Comment: Thank you ! I put : `php /var/www/html/phpscript.php` in a .sh file that I tried to run by executing the .sh file and that worked, but with cron `52 22 * * * /root/scripts/script_for_php.sh` that didn't worked..

Answer (score 0):

I also needed a cron job in order to run a php file with a null output:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path/to/script/cron.php >/dev/null
```

The hosting service does not allow "special" characters (>) in the input text for the command, so it had to be executed inside an executable .sh file (*with `-rwxr-xr-x` permissions or 755*).

I was better oriented when read good information at [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304210313/https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215767107-Execution-environment-of-a-cron-job).

You could try:

**/root/scripts/backup_bdd.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
php -f /var/www/html/phpscript.php
```

***Note**: when .sh file is already edited remember to double check permissions before creating cron job. Some local/online editors could change your file permissions to `-rw-r--r--`/644 after save file:*

```
$ chmod +x /root/scripts/backup_bdd.sh
```

And for the cron job, the 'Command to run' that works for me, is by adding at the beginning the *sh* utility:

```
sh -f /root/scripts/backup_bdd.sh
```

At the end the cron job looks like this:

```
50 19 * * * sh -f /root/scripts/backup_bdd.sh
```

---

Don't know much about bash but if it doesn't work try the following (it depends on your system environment):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
php -f /var/www/html/phpscript.php
```

maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29729106/496176):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PHP=`which php`
$PHP -f /var/www/html/phpscript.php
```

or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5506970/496176):

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
php -f /var/www/html/phpscript.php
```

*Note 2: I also tried `crontab` commands without success (shared hosting).*

Good luck